# unnecessary exclamation marks(!)'s in HTML code

Tags: python, html, email, html-email

I am emailing the content of a text file "gerrit.txt" @ http://pastie.org/8289257  in outlook using the below code,
however after the email is sent when I look at the source code( @http://pastie.org/8289379) of the email in outlook ,i see unnecessary 
exclamation markds(!)'s in the code which is messing up the output, can anyone provide inputs on why is it so and how to avoid this ?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP

def email (body,subject):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body, 'html')
    msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=UTF8"
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    s = SMTP('localhost',25)
    s.sendmail('userid@company.com', ['userid2@company.com'],msg=msg.as_string())

def main ():
    # open gerrit.txt and read the content into body
    with open('gerrit.txt', 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()
    subject = "test email"
    email(body,subject)
    print "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Python doesn't add those exclamation marks, I can tell you that much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I am running this on a ubuntu machine..does it have anything do with the platform?any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: No idea; depends on what other components touch that email. You can write or print the `msg.as_string()` part and verify that no exclamation marks are present, for a start.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - msg.as_string() doesnt have it either,any other ideas?

Comment: Nope; check your email server. You didn't provide any details of that setup.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - servers settings ...Internal POP setting:
     Server name: qcmail1.company.com
     Port: 995
     Encryption method: SSL
Internal IMAP setting:
     Server name: qcmail1.company.com
     Port: 993
     Encryption method: SSL

Answer (score 8):

Some info available here: http://bugs.python.org/issue6327

> Note that mailservers have a 990-character limit on each line
>   contained within an email message. If an email message is sent that
>   contains lines longer than 990-characters, those lines will be
>   subdivided by additional line ending characters, which can cause
>   corruption in the email message, particularly for HTML content. To
>   prevent this from occurring, add your own line-ending characters at
>   appropriate locations within the email message to ensure that no lines
>   are longer than 990 characters.

I think you must split your html to some lines. You can use [textwrap.wrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) method.

Comment: Thanks! Splitting it after 990 chars helped

Answer (score 1):

adding a '\n' in between my html string , some random 20 characters before "!" was appearing solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, Its because outlook doesn't support line more than 990 characters it starts giving below issues.

1. Nested tables
2. Color change of column heading
3. Adding unwanted ! marks .

Here is solution for the same.

if you are adding for single line you can add

```
"line[:40]" + \r\n + "line[40:]".
```

If you are forming a table then you can put the same in loop like

```
"<td>" + line[j][:40]+"\r\n"+line[j][40:] + "</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the html is being constructed outside of the python script and is passed in as an argument. I added line breaks after each html tag within the python script which resolved my issue:

```
import re
result_html = re.sub(">", ">\n", html_body)
```